# Control the running order of the Spock specs

Tags: gradle, junit, spock

I'm trying to run Spock tests in a specific order, I'm using gradle to run the tests.
I want to be able to control the test order.
I've found I can use the suit, but it doesn't scale for my tests.
is there any other way to run spock tests in a specific order?

Comment: can you be more specific with `specific order`?

Comment: Tests should be independent of each other, why do you want to impose some order?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @chenrui By specific order I mean that I want to run the a certain spec before other specs run. Leonard, ideally you're right, but we'd like to avoid certain complications caused by other solutions and were wondering if such a solution exists and if it does - how complicated it is. Generally, the spec tests a screen that only shows up once, at the first run of the application, so it can interfere with other Specs.